# TikZ and animateinline

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animate

I have 2 presentations:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
         \useasboundingbox (3,0.5) rectangle (7,4.5);
         \pause
         \draw [name path=circle, line width=1](5,2.5) circle (2);
         \pause
         \draw [name path=line, line width=1](2,1)--(7,4) ;
         \path [name intersections={of = circle and line}];
         \coordinate (A) at (intersection-1);
         \coordinate (B) at (intersection-2);
         \pause
         \filldraw(A) circle (1.5pt);
         \pause    
         \filldraw(B) circle (1.5pt);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{90}
      \multiframe{121}{iAngle=0+3}
         {\begin{tikzpicture}
             \useasboundingbox (3,0.5) rectangle (7,4.5);
             \draw [line width=1](5,2.5) arc (0:\iAngle:2);
         \end{tikzpicture}}
      \end{animateinline}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to combine it with all functionality. I do it this way:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{center}
         \begin{tikzpicture}
            \useasboundingbox (3,0.5) rectangle (7,4.5);
            \pause
                  \begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{90}
                     \multiframe{121}{iAngle=0+3}
                     {\draw [line width=1](5,2.5) arc (0:\iAngle:2);}
                  \end{animateinline}
            \draw [name path=circle, line width=1](5,2.5) circle (2);
            \pause
            \draw [name path=line, line width=1](2,1)--(7,4) ;
            \path [name intersections={of = circle and line}];
            \coordinate (A) at (intersection-1);
            \coordinate (B) at (intersection-2);
            \pause
            \filldraw(A) circle (1.5pt);
            \pause    
            \filldraw(B) circle (1.5pt);
         \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong? And how can I do it right?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you mind telling us what is going wrong?

Comment: ! Package animate Error: Contents of first frame must not have zero width.
See the animate package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
l.27    \end{frame}
Possible reason: \begin{animateinline}{...} immediately followed by \newframe

Comment: Your examples are not identical: You changed the order of the `tikzpicture` and the `animateinline` environments in your second example. Otherwise you get the mentioned error, too.

Comment: @Paul : Your comment should be part of the question. Would you please edit it?

Answer (score 3):

A TikZ `\draw` alone doesn't produce a box with non-zero width and height, but `animateinline` expects something of non-zero size in order to produce animation frames.

Therefore a `tikzpicture` environment must surround the graphical objects inside the `animateinline` environment (as in the standalone animation in the 2nd code box). But you removed it from the "combined" document (3rd code box). Hence, the reported error

```
! Package animate Error: Contents of first frame must not have zero width...
```

The animation should be saved in an ordinary `lrbox` and put as a `\node` on the second slide (`\node<2> ...`). The final animation frame should be repeated on the slides after the slide with the animation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{animate}

\newsavebox\myAnim

\begin{document}

  \begin{lrbox}{\myAnim}
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{30}
    \multiframe{121}{iAngle=0+3}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (3,0.5) rectangle (7,4.5);
        \draw [line width=1](5,2.5) arc (0:\iAngle:2);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{animateinline}
  \end{lrbox}

  \begin{frame}
     \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
           \useasboundingbox (3,0.5) rectangle (7,4.5);
           \pause
           %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
           % animated object only on the second (<2>) slide
           %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
           \node<2> [inner sep=0, outer sep=0, anchor=south west] at (3,0.5) {\usebox\myAnim};
           \draw [name path=circle, line width=1](5,2.5) circle (2);
           %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
           \pause
           %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
           % repeat last animation frame on the slides to follow
           \begin{scope} %limit the clipping path on the `arc' object
             \clip (3,0.5) rectangle (7,4.5);
             \draw [line width=1](5,2.5) arc (0:360:2);
           \end{scope}
           %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
           \draw [name path=line, line width=1](2,1)--(7,4) ;
           \path [name intersections={of = circle and line}];
           \coordinate (A) at (intersection-1);
           \coordinate (B) at (intersection-2);
           \pause
           \filldraw(A) circle (1.5pt);
           \pause    
           \filldraw(B) circle (1.5pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{center}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```